# How do I script for "If %variable%==*ANYTHING* perform task"?

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, variables

I am trying to add to a script that I have been working on (and Compo has been a big help with) to incorporate user input. I currently have:

```
SET /p KIOSK=Enter NEW account here or leave blank to QUERY for current account  _
ECHO. 
IF "%KIOSK%"==* @%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /V "DefaultUserName" /D %KIOSK% /F 1>NUL && ECHO Kiosk account changed to %KIOSK% || ECHO Kisok account NOT changed 
IF "%KIOSK%"=="" ECHO Querying for current account . . .
```

What I want is for `@%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe ADD` to change the `DefaultUserName` to whatever the user enters. The `KIOSK` will look something like this: "K#######" where `#` could be any number 0-9. So basically, `IF %KIOSK%==` literally anything, I want the `DefaultUserName` changed to that value. I am not sure how to get this result. And yes, I know it has to be run as Admin.

Comment: `if not "%variable%"==""` or `if defined variable`?

Comment: ```IF NOT "%variable%"==""``` worked. Thank you @aschipfl

Comment: I'd have to add, that I'm not convinced that what you are doing is the using correct methodology. Surely your end user cannot just type and `[ENTER]` anything as an account name when prompted. Not only will some characters and names be disallowed, it seems as if you would need to verify that the typed input first of all begins with the alphabet string character `K` and is followed only by a series of integer characters. Then you would probably need to search the system to ensure that there is an existing Assigned Access account with that name, before setting it as the default at startup/login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following commented code to process the user entered string:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

:PromptUser
set "KIOSK="
set /P "KIOSK=Enter NEW account here or leave blank to QUERY for current account: "
if not defined KIOSK goto QueryAccount

rem Remove all double quotes from user entered string.
set "KIOSK=%KIOSK:"=%"
rem Prompt the user again on having only double quotes entered.
if not defined KIOSK goto PromptUser
rem Prompt the user again if the first characeter is not an upper case K.
if not "%KIOSK:~0,1%" == "K" goto PromptUser
rem Prompt the user again if there is not at least one more character.
if "%KIOSK:~1%" == "" goto PromptUser
rem Prompt the user again if the user entered string contains
rem other characters than digits after the first character K.
for /F "tokens=1* delims=0123456789" %%I in ("%KIOSK%") do if not "%%J" == "" goto PromptUser

set "RegExe=%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe"
if exist "%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\reg.exe" set "RegExe=%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\reg.exe"
rem if exist "%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\reg.exe" set "RegExe=%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\reg.exe"
%RegExe% ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /V "DefaultUserName" /D %KIOSK% /F 1>NUL && echo Kiosk
goto EndBatch

:QueryAccount
echo Querying for current account ...

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

I am not sure if `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` should be updated with `DefaultUserName` which does not exist by default on Windows 7 x64 or `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` which contains by default an empty string value with the name `DefaultUserName`.

The code above adds it to registry key for 64-bit applications on Windows AMD64 while using the commented line with `SysWOW64` would add the registry value to registry key for 32-bit applications on Windows AMD64.

See also the Microsoft documentation pages:

- [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details)
- [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector)
- [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/shared-registry-keys)

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `reg /?`
- `reg add /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`